# Simple Harmonic Motion homework

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, oscillators

Suppose we have a rod of mass $m$ and length $l$ which is pivoted at center and two springs of spring constant $k$ are attached at opposite ends so that it performs simple Harmonic motion when displace through small distance $x$. 
So I approached problem by writing total energy of system at any time which is 
$$\frac{1}{2} I.w^2 + \frac{1}{2}k x^2 + \frac{1}{2}k x^2 =E$$ now we know total energy does not changes wrt time so I took derivative with respect to time so becomes $$2.\frac{1}{2} I.(\frac{v}{R^2} .)a+ 2.k x.v =0$$ and $$a= -2R^2\frac{k}{I}x$$ where$$I=\frac{ml^2}{12}$$and hence making relation for simple harmonic motion but my answer does not matches?

Comment: Can you add a diagram? The energy equation seems incorrect since "springs in opposite ends" should not have the same displacement x in the equation of energy.

Comment: Here's the diagram sorry imgur is not working  http://s11.postimg.org/tvdo8ogpb/20141012_153023.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay My approach was correct and Radius of rotation should be half the length of rod so $2R=l$ and solving thereafter will give correct answer.